# Is it normal to have a list of objects in an object?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to OO design, and I wondering whether it is typical to have designs where objects contain lists of other objects. An example is below:

```
// Person object containing a list of phone numbers
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Phone> Contacts { get; set; }

    public void AddPhoneNumber(Phone phone)
    {
        Contacts.Add(phoneNumber);
    }
}

// Phone object
public class Phone
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

// Example code to establish an object:
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.FirstName = "John";
p1.LastName = "Smith";
p1.AddPhoneNumber(new Phone() { Number = "555957000" });
p1.AddPhoneNumber(new Phone() { Number = "555579561" });
```

Is there a better way to structure this that simplifies the design and allows easier access to the data? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your structure in terms of classes seem fine. Can you post as to how you are accessing the data for storing/retrieving? Might help you improve with that aspect of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely fine to have an object contains  list of object. In `OOPs` this is called **Composition**, which represent strong relationship between participating `class`.

Comment: Thanks for the term, I'll do additional research.

Comment: I liked your spirit:) There are two term  **Composition** and **Association** please read both term. Can you please mark it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

> I wondering whether it is typical to have designs where objects
>   contain lists of other objects.

Absolutely, this is normal as an object can contain lists that belong to only that particular object. One of many examples is when you're traversing a binary tree or such you could have each node have their own list which identifies their children. There are many more cases in which an object should/could contain their own list.

Going back to your code, you seem to have an error because the code below states that the list will contain `Phone` objects.

```
public List<Phone> Contacts { get; set; }
```

but yet you're passing in a string object rather than a phone object.

```
public void AddPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)  
{
     Contacts.Add(phoneNumber); // this code shouldnt compile
}
```

rather what you can do is this:

```
public void AddPhoneNumber(string phoneNumber)  
{
    Contacts.Add(new Phone() { Number = phoneNumber });
}
```

Comment: You are right, that is definitely an error. I fixed the method parameter to be a Phone object instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It's perfectly valid to have a list of objects within an object.

Though adding a string to your List of Phone objects will throw an error.

You can add a phone number like so:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p1.Contacts.Add(new Phone() { Number = "555579561" });
```